# Where to find international train fares for Europe

Tags: budget, trains, europe, fares

I'm based in Germany, and the [Deutsche Bahn website](http://bahn.de) is great for scheduling international train travel.  It knows all about the train times and connections all over Europe.  However, it rarely shows fares for trips which cross a border.  All the other national train operators' websites I've tried have the same problem.  This makes them rather useless for comparing prices when I've got a destination in mind and am trying to choose between, say, taking the train, flying, or renting a car...  or alternately if I've got a budget but no particular destination in mind, and would like to see what places I can afford to visit.

Is there any website which will let me plan train journeys in Europe, and give me the exact or even approximate fares?  (That is, something similar to the many flight search websites like [Kayak](http://kayak.co.uk).)

Comment: @Vince - gah, well spotted.  I couldn't believe there wasn't one already, looked briefly but no luck, so I answered.  Joined your vote to close now.

Comment: @MarkMayo But your answer is not duplicate :)

Comment: yeah I got lucky :) Perhaps @mindcorrosive can merge them or something...if not, I can always move it there manually.

Comment: No duplicate. Schedules and fares are two pairs of shoes

Answer (score 3):

[RailEurope](http://www.raileurope.co.uk/) works pretty well for this.

I just tested it by searching for a train from Paris to Rome.  It immediately showed me a few, including those that change in Milan.

Oddly, their [Australian](http://www.raileurope.com.au/) site seems to give a nicer layout of prices for me.  I don't know if the prices differ at all, but it may be worth your time investigating.

Comment: yup, and with RailEurope, Voyages-sncf.com is targetting covering the whole Europe. Their idea is to bet on international trains and their websites will all offer trains across Europe, sooner or later. Anyway, European Union is pushing the retailers to show both air and train fares for comparison.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere which trains are covered by RailEurope and which are not? My searches between a few cities either don't find all (or the most reasonable) connections, don't find any connections at all or give me an error message that the trip would involve too many train changes to book the trip online.

Comment: While RailEurope does give fares for many countries, beware that it's often cheaper to shop around and book segments separately. A lot of train companies have seat quotas for reduced rates, so this will vary depending on exactly when you book, but I'd rarely expect RailEurope to come up with the best price.